# Angular.js doesn't refresh the repeater after $scope.var changes but only after refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I thought 2 ways binding was angular thing:

I can post from a form to the controller, and if I refresh the page I see my input on the page:

```
$scope.loadInput = function () {

    $scope.me.getList('api') //Restangular - this part works
    .then(function(userinput) {

        $scope.Input = $scope.Input.concat(userinput);
        // scope.input is being referenced by ng-repeater in the page 
        // so after here a refresh should be triggered.

    },function(response){
        /*@alon TODO: better error handling than console.log..*/
        console.log('Error with response:', response.status);
    });
};
```

In the html page the `ng-repeater` iterates over the array of `for i in input`. but the new input from the form isn't shown unless I refresh the page.

I'll be glad for help with this - thanks!

Comment: have you tried putting $scope.Input = $scope.Input.concat(userinput); inside $scope.$apply ?

Comment: @az7ar: If `$scope.me.getList` returns an angular `$q` promise, then we do not need to start another digest loop in its callbacks.

Comment: @az7ar yeah.. I did, didn't help, just got console errors about digest already running..

Comment: Can you show the markup (html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `$scope.$apply`:

```
$scope.loadInput = function () {
        $scope.me.getList('api') //Restangular - this part works
        .then(function(userinput) {
               $scope.$apply(function(){ //let angular know the changes

                $scope.Input = $scope.Input.concat(userinput);
             });

            },function(response){
                /*@alon TODO: better error handling than console.log..*/
                console.log('Error with response:', response.status);
            });
    };
```

The reason why: Your ajax is async, it will execute in the next turn, but at this time, you already leaves angular cycle. Angular is not aware of the changes, we have to use `$scope.$apply` here to enter angular cycle. This case is a little bit different from using services from angular like `$http`, when you use `$http` service and handle your response inside `.success`, angular is aware of the changes.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PnYvz/2/) that does not work. You would notice that the first click does not refresh the view.

```
setTimeout(function(){
             $scope.checkboxes = $scope.checkboxes.concat([{"text": "text10", checked:true}]);
         },1);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PnYvz/1/) that works by using `$scope.$apply`

```
setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.$apply(function(){
         $scope.checkboxes = $scope.checkboxes.concat([{"text": "text10", checked:true}]);
            });
        },1);
```

Comment: @Davin Tryon: `setTimeout` here is just to simulate async function

Comment: Actually this throws errors about digest already in progress. building the functionality with a service and $q did the trick, But I'll award this a correct answer because it led me in the right direction (although using apply is an angular anti pattern I think)

Comment: @SlightlyCuban long time ago, not sure I remember, but there are two mistakes I made here (I was an angular youngling then.. )
1. In the code above I reassign $scope.input, so the live binding is gone.. Instead we should iterate over the ```userdata``` and push each item into the **existing** $scope.input.
of course $scope.input should exist before and outside the function.
2. I directly call the http within the controller. That's an angular anti pattern. angular is (mostly) an mvvm - this kind of communication should be in a service, where the controller should get the data from the service

Comment: @SlightlyCuban: as I remember, the promise returned from `getList` is not an angular one. Therefore, angular is not aware of the update from the success callback. The only thing to do is just to wrap the success callback inside `$scope.$apply`. If we use angular functions inside `getList` (like `$q`), then it should work without `$scope.$apply`

Comment: @rob.alarcon: IMO, It may not be a good angular practice. But as we're updating something outside of angular, we must let angular aware of the changes. It's better to use something more angular like $q promise.