# Angular js data duplicate on page refresh

Tags: angularjs

Im pretty new to angular Js and im having issue  with data duplication when i refresh the page

Im using this Init function in order to get the data

```
    $scope.init = function() {
  $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: path
  }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      $scope.Users = response.data;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    $scope.alerts = [{
      type: 'danger',
      msg: 'ITS MIKI fault...  ' + response.data
    }];
  });

}
```

I tried  to **Delete $scope.Users;** before the get http   but it didn't work.

What is the best way to override the scope wham im doing the get again ?

Comment: $scope.$apply will help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular.js doesn't refresh the repeater after $scope.var changes but only after refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19516098/angular-js-doesnt-refresh-the-repeater-after-scope-var-changes-but-only-after)